# verb "influence" + on + object

Tags: word-usage

Can I put "on" after a verb "influence" in a sentence?

I've come across a sentence below.

> Many researchers have completed a range of studies to evaluate the relationship of intrinsic, extrinsic and amotivation, particularly on how it **influences on** a student's academic achievement.

I think the last part of the sentence should be "how it influences a student's academic achievement".

I mean, grammar-wise.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. But your sentence makes no sense. What are the adjectives **intrinsic** and **extrinsic** modifying? Do you mean **motivation**.  And what does the **it** refer to? Please look at your sentence again.

Comment: @RonaldSole I think this is academic speak (i.e., an unnecessarily fancy, ornate and, in my humble opinion, obnoxious writing style) meaning "internal motivation, external motivation and absence of motivation" - whether a student is self-motivated, motivated by outside factors or not motivated at all.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's used by academics, it's a parallelism error—one of several errors (in addition to "it" and "influences on") in the sentence.